# In an HTML table, how can I center the contents of the cells (not the table itself)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, internet-explorer-6

Given that I'm allowed to use static JS and HTML tags (only those supported by IE6), how can I center the contents of the cells in an HTML table (not the table itself)?

Comment: gah! why do people insist on still supporting IE6???? I know you're going to get perfectly good answers for this question, but there's so much that IE6 can't do or does wrong that you're really hobbling your site if you insist on supporting it. My advice is to do the minimum to get your site *working* in IE6, but don't bother trying to make it look good.

Comment: @Spudley: IE6 is still the standard browser in some companies, so for some of us our hands are tied. At my company we are only now just rolling out IE8 and allowing non-IT desktop users to use FireFox if they prefer to do so. We have around 80,000 machines, so rollouts and upgrades take time.

Comment: @richard EV - yeah, I know, that was a bit of a rant. Sorry :)  But it was as much aimed at the companies that haven't upgraded (or who tied themselves too tightly in the first place) as at anyone actually developing the sites.

Comment: @Spudley. No worries ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the css style `text-align: center;`, either as an inline style (below) or as a css style applied to all `<td>` elements (as suggested in Joel's answer).

```
<td style="text-align:center;">
    Table contents here
</td>
```

Answer (score 3):

IE 6 supports CSS. In the head of the document:

```
<style type="text/css">

td {
    text-align: center;
}

</style>
```

If you have more than one table and only want to do this to a specific table, you can use the selectors to get even more granular.

Comment: IE6 supports fairly minimal CSS, but it does at least support this.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `align` attribute for `<td>`.

Comment: http://w3fools.com - please don't link to w3schools, it is a bad source of information.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution with only html tags.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><center>Data</center></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But the other solutions are better in view of best practices